# how to dict map each word to list of words which follow it in python?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

what i am trying to do :
dict that maps each word that appears in the file
to a list of all the words that immediately follow that word in the file.
The list of words can be be in any order and should include
duplicates.So for example the key "and" might have the list
["then", "best", "then", "after", ...] listing
all the words which came after "and" in the text.

```
  f = open(filename,'r')

  s = f.read().lower()

  words = s.split()#list of words in the file

  dict = {}

  l = []

  i = 0

  for word in words:

      if i < (len(words)-1) and word == words[i]:

          dict[word] = l.append(words[i+1])  

  print dict.items()

  sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies, since I am learning, I wanted to know why my program isn't working. I could solve it in anothe rmethod, but I don't think the original concept is wrong , just cusrious if there is any syntax issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is helpful for such iterations. For simplicity, I've invented a string rather than loaded from a file.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import string

x = '''This is a random string with some 
string elements repeated. This is so 
that, with someluck, we can solve a problem.'''

translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
y = x.lower().translate(translator).replace('\n', '').split(' ')

result = defaultdict(list)

for i, j in zip(y[:], y[1:]):
    result[i].append(j)

# result
# defaultdict(list,
#             {'a': ['random', 'problem'],
#              'can': ['solve'],
#              'elements': ['repeated'],
#              'is': ['a', 'so'],
#              'random': ['string'],
#              'repeated': ['this'],
#              'so': ['that'],
#              'solve': ['a'],
#              'some': ['string'],
#              'someluck': ['we'],
#              'string': ['with', 'elements'],
#              'that': ['with'],
#              'this': ['is', 'is'],
#              'we': ['can'],
#              'with': ['some', 'someluck']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultdict for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

words = ["then", "best", "then", "after"]

words_dict = defaultdict(list)
for w1,w2 in zip(words, words[1:]):
    words_dict[w1].append(w2)
```

Results:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'then': ['best', 'after'], 'best': ['then']})
```